# How can I install Ubuntu on a USB external drive for booting?

Tags: installation, boot, usb, live-usb

I want to boot Ubuntu on my mac air(2010) using my external 1TB drive.

I converted the install to `.img` fine in Terminal.
Now i need to make a bootable usb drive to install

I tried to do the `sudo` command but it told me my device cannot be read by this computer after it waited a few minutes.

I then tried unetbootin. But it says the bootable usb device cannot be used on a mac.
I just want to get Ubuntu.

This is the error I get when I get trough step 9.

```
The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.
```

Everything else works great, until here.

I took a chance and plugged in the USB drive unetbootin said could not be used to boot, well it does work. I did the trial, then successfully installed Ubuntu on the external drive partition.

Answer (score 0):

[How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) has Mac-specific, step-by-step instructions on USB Flash Drive preparation as does [Installation/FromImgFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromImgFiles#Mac_OS_X). Please try that on your external drive as if it was a flash drive, and let us know if there's a problem by editing your original question and copying the error message into the question.